# OnActivityResult holds previous values

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I have made a pretty complicated app so I will try to explain it step by step.

I have a chat screen where 2 people can send messages and there is a `ToggleButton` at top. When a user clicks the `ToggleButton`, and activity is started by calling:  `startActivityForResult(intent,1);`.

In the new activity, the user chooses items from a list and clicks `DONE`. When the user clicked this button the items that he chose are transferred back to the chat by calling

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        if(resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_OK){
            confirmedItems = (ArrayList<Items>)data.getSerializableExtra("items");
            DateInMillis = data.getLongExtra( "dateInMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        if (resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, In the app, I have more activities such as `profile activity`, `search` which I can get to them from my chat activity by using:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId( R.id.nav_profile );
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( item -> {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            startActivity(new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_home:
            startActivity(new Intent(ChatActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_search:
            startActivity(new Intent(ChatActivity.this, SearchActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
} );
```

Let say I entered the chat and clicked the `ToggleButton` but didn't choose any item. Instead, I go back to profile activity. Then, I return to the chat activity and continue with the process. In this case, for some reason, it seems like the app adds 2 things:

1) The items that were chosen last time

2) The new selected items

Is there a reason that It saves the previous results as well?

Im pretty stuck on it for a while and I cant understand why it seems like it is called twice.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly does _"go back to profile activity"_ and _"return to the chat activity"_ mean here? Could you clarify what this looks like in terms of the activity back stack?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it is what you meant.

Comment: I didn't get your question much but this may solve your problem, try calling finish(); method when you go back to other activity.

Comment: Before I perform StartActivity to one of the profile/search activities?